# How to say “Go all the way” in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

I want to know how I can say Go all the way in Latin.
What I found is *Ut omni modo*. Is it correct?

I’ll use it to say something like: Go all the way what ever this will cost you, when we are talking about goal and dreams. But I want to keep it just simple as "Go all the way". I don’t know if you understand me!

Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 2):

It often happens that a literal translation is not good for a motto.
The idea has to be re-expressed from scratch to get a more natural wording.
If I understood correctly, the intended meaning is "do whatever is necessary to pursue your goals".

My suggestion would be:

> *Ne quid obstet.*
> = May nothing prohibit.
> ≈ May nothing come between you and your goal.

This is an idiomatic phrasing in Latin (cf. *ne quid divini humanive obstet, quominus…* in Livy) and even pithier than the English original.
It has none of the same words by any comparison, but I think it conveys the same message.

---

*Ut omni modo* could be understood as "so that in every way".
It makes little sense to me and does not seem to convey a message anywhere near the intended one.

Comment: llmavirta: Related to your Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/12872/1982, in "ne quid obstet..." (Livy 9.8.6) how does "quid" come to mean "nothing"? I cannot find a listing for this. (The clock-inscription at Wells Cathedral: "ne quid pereat" = "let nothing perish".). Does it arise from the neuter form of "quis" = "Who?".  A person cannot be a neuter, therefore "quid" came to mean "nobody" or "nothing"--is this correct?

Comment: @tony It works the same way for all genders. If the obstacles are people, then *ne quis obstet* would work fine. This will probably not surprise you, but I recommend asking a separate question on this use of *ne quis/quid*. It is idiomatic in Latin, but I admit it is also quite puzzling at first. Or at least was to me.

Comment: @tony the inscription on the clock is referring to time: ne quid pereat means "let not any (time) go to waste"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one would need some kind of context. *Totam ire viam* perhaps, *usque ad metam pergere*, *iter perficere usque ad terminum*? There may well be a classical equivalent hiding somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

The extremum is all the way in Latin. So, to make it a command you would say:

```
I ad extremum (go all the way)
```

If you want to make it stronger and more colloquial, you can use the word ultimum, so you might write:

```
Gere ad ultimum! (Go all the way!)
```

Gero is the word used when carrying on an activity, so when you doing things you are ger-ing them. So, if you are traveling to a place you go (eo) there, but if you are doing things, then you carry on (geris). Gere is the imperative form of gero. Do it!