# Translating "I will go all the way"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, sentence-translation

I need help translating the English sentence "I will go all the way" into Latin. This will be used as a motto.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is [this older question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/15303/79) the same as yours? If not, how does it differ from what you're after?

Answer (score -1):

That would most commonly be:

*Ad ultimum agam*

For example, we have from Livy:

```
...si fidem ad ultimum fratri praestitisset
```

...if he would remain faithful to his brother to the end.

Comment: Why _agere_ for "go"?

Comment: @Draconis That is the word Romans used in that situation. For example, in Plautus when one character wants to ask another where is he going, he says "Quo te agis?"

Comment: L&S lists this meaning under [ago](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dago): "se agere, to betake one's self, i. e. to go, to come." You need the reflexive pronoun for this to work though, so you should have "**me** agam."