# What is the Role of "Quid" in "ne quid obstet"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

In his answer to Q: [How to say “Go all the way” in Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/15303/1982), Joonas provided a quote from Titus Livius (9.8.6):

> "ne quid obstet..." =

> "let nothing obstruct...".

How does "quid" come to mean "nothing"? (There is a well-known example at Wells Cathedral: an inscription on the clock:

> "ne quid pereat." =

> "Let nothing perish.")

I cannot find a listing for this. Does it arise from the neuter form ("quid") of the interrogative pronoun, "quis?"= "Who?"?. A person cannot be a neuter therefore it came to mean "nobody" or "nothing"--is this guess correct?

In a Comment (the same question) Joonas pointed out that if the obstruction is a person, then "ne quis obstet..." would be correct. This indicates, I think, that the neuter form "quid" would give the required "nobody"/ "nothing" meaning.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The negated *quid* or *quis* is essentially short for *aliquid*/*aliquis*, so the meaning is "not anything shall obstruct" and "not anything shall perish", and "not anything" means of course "nothing".

Comment: Thank you.  When reading Joonas's Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/12872/1982, I wondered why "quid pro quo" was never given as "aliquid pro aliquo", which seems to be a much more correct way of translating "something for something".

Comment: What is the difference from *nihil* as in the indicative *nihil obstat*?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава The big diffference here is between *obstat* and *obstet*. One is indicative, the other subjunctive. The distinction between the two subjunctives *ne quid obstet* and *nihil obstet* is likely in the type of subjunctive it is. *Ne quid obstet* is likely a final clause, "lest anything obstruct," while *nihil obstet* might indicate an unintended result, "things just happened in such away that there was nothing obstructing.

Answer (score 6):

@gmvh gave you the answer, but I want to elaborate some. There's a commonly heard mnemonic in Dutch schools:

> Na **sī**, **nisi**, **num** en **nē** gaat **ali**- niet met **quis**je mee.

A equivalent but slightly less elegant rhyme in English might be:

> After **sī**, **nisi**, **num**, and **nē**, *aliquis*'s **ali**- falls away.

To this canonical list should be added at least **ut** and **alius**: in constructions with these words, you should never find *aliquis* (noun or adjective), but always *quis*. Outside of these situations, *quis* as an indefinite pronoun is very rare. (You point out *quid pro quo*, which is an example, but keep in mind that that's not just post-Classical, but actually post-Medieval.)

The analysis in traditions that follow this mnemonic is that that *quis* is exactly equivalent to *aliquis*, but that's not universal: [Allen & Greenough](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/indefinite-pronouns) consider *quis* to be less definite than *aliquis*, at one end of a scale that goes from *quis* over *quispiam* and *aliquis* to *quīdam*. I don't think I agree with that.

Comment: There is even a [cartoon Ali](http://www.latein-online.net/index.php?section=ali.htm) (an elephant for some reason).